# Transparent colours and images are shown in red

Tags: macos, graphics, color

For a long time I have had an issue with display color—it strangely has more red color in it as I can see. As far as I understand, it is due to how transparency is displayed.

The upper menu bar is having this redness, or in Preview.app for example, when viewing PDF files, it is blinking between normal white color and red background transparent color as you keep scrolling.

I tried to calibrate system color in System Preferences, but without any positive result.

Here are examples when using viewer to read some pdf file:

1. Here is how all the images are displayed (this redness I tried to explain above):

   [image]
2. While scrolling, transparent red layer blinks from normal

   [image]
   [image]

This is only an example, It's not an issue *only* with this app, it's just easy to see it using this app.

Comment: Please add a screenshot if possible.

Comment: Is your desktop background red?

Comment: klanomath, I add screenshots, take a look please.

Comment: @sandric Did you 'doctor up' the images with Photoshop to illustrate the effect or is it really visible in the screenshots? Which system do you use?

Comment: @klanomath, what, 'doctor up'? Nope, this is exactly what I'm seeing with my eyes. I'm using Yosemite on macbook air, mid 2012. But this problem was even before I upgraded system. I remember that it started when I plugged additional monitor, and saw there such effect, and then tried to change smth, don't remember what, and end up having such effect even without additional screen, and on macbook itself, now trying to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: @sandric Please try `defaults delete -g CGContextHighlight2xScaledImages` entered in Terminal and hit the enter key and check again

Comment: @klanomath, damn, its it, I had to reload system, but it fixed it, thanks a lot. Thou I dont understand why is it worked because I do not remember to set any default params for CGContextHighlight2xScaledImages... But its solved for now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Terminal and enter:

  `defaults delete -g CGContextHighlight2xScaledImages` and hit the Enter key.
- Restart your Mac.

This will disable highlighting non-retina images with a red overlay (probably in Apple apps only).

To reenable it open Terminal and just enter:

`defaults write -g CGContextHighlight2xScaledImages YES` and hit the Enter key.